# Global place to fetch menu items in NextJs from getServerSideProps or getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Is there any global place in Next.js to fetch menu-items(server-side) that I can pass to my Layout component.

Since, I can't do that in `index.js` as if somebody directly opens different route for eg: `/about` then the data will not be fetch.

I tried doing that in `_app` by implementing it's static `getInitialProps` method but I'm not sure if it's a good practice and also it will disable Automatic Static Optimization in pages without Static Generation.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

`getInitialProps` is the old way of what you are doing to do. But `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` will replace `getInitialProps`

[image: getInitialProps seem to be deprecated soon]
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

But `getServerSideProps` can't be used in _app for global data fetching for now. [It will be introduced later.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10874#discussioncomment-1085) Until then, I think you have these options:

1. Keep using `getInitialProps` and trade static optimization
2. Get the menu items on the client side and render an activity indicator (a spinner?) until the data is ready.
3. Add a `getServerSideProps` wrapper and a HoC like `withMenuItem` and wrap all pages and their `getServerSideProps` exports.

Comment: `Add a getServerSideProps wrapper and a HoC like withMenuItem and wrap all pages and their getServerSideProps exports.` Can you detail this option? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An example of the getServerSideProps HoC

```
const withGlobalData = (getStaticProps) => async (...props) => {
  const result = await getStaticProps(...props)

  const staticProps = result?.props || {}

  const global = { menuItems: ['home', 'about'] } // your global props

  return {...result, props: { ...staticProps, global }}
}
```

Use this function as a wrapper around the getStaticProps function like so.

```
export const getStaticProps = withGlobalData( async ({ context }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      // page specific props
    }
  }
} )
```

Comment: How would one call this?

Comment: I  added an example in my existing post

Comment: But using this HoC will re-execute the fetch to menu item in all pages right ?